# Kotlin: Expecting member declaration

Tags: kotlin

I'm learning some oop with kotlin.  I'm getting the error when in my Bike class I create an object to my Bell class and then call a function in the Bell class.

```
public class Bike(nbrWheels: Int){

    val numberOfWheels: Int = nbrWheels

    val bell = Bell()
    bell.ringBell()

}
```

The error is on the line: `bell.ringBell()`

Is this possible in kotlin?  Am I just doing it wrong?

Comment: You are trying to call the function in the middle of nowhere. You can't do that. Functions must be called as an assignment of a property, within another function, or in a constructor/`init` block.

Comment: @Tenfour04  Thanks. Would you give me a simple example?  Or, point me to one?  I am new to this.

Comment: ` val ring = bell.ringBell()` That works.

Comment: I'm not sure what an example would be since it is something you can't do, not something you can do. If you just drop a function call in a random location, it is meaningless. When would it be called? It would be undefined.